# Bootstrap 5 Accordion Header Border Issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a Bootstrap 5 accordion header with an icon drop-up menu. The issue is the bottom border disappears underneath the icon and I cannot figure our why?

**HTML**

```
<div class="w-50 mt-5 mx-auto">
  <div class="accordion favorites-folder" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <div class="accordion-header">
        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Accordion Header
        </button>
        <div class="btn-group dropup">
          <button type="button" class="header-actions" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical"></i>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
            <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button"> Rename</button></li>
            <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Delete</button></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a enim quis justo lacinia ullamcorper quis ac nunc. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer vitae nisi vitae eros iaculis interdum tempor a sapien. Nulla pulvinar, mi quis tincidunt tristique, eros elit venenatis arcu, in dapibus dolor turpis eget nisi.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.favorites-folder {
    background-image: none;

    .accordion-item {

        .accordion-header {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;

            .accordion-button {
                background-color: #fff;
                padding: .5rem 1rem;

                &:not(.collapsed) {
                    background-color: #fff;

                    &::after {
                        background-image: none;
                    }
                }

                &:after {
                    background-image: none;
                }
            }

            .header-actions {
                background: transparent;
                border: none;
                padding-right: 1rem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[Link to CodePen](https://codepen.io/Pixel-Paul/pen/dyQjQgE)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the bottom border is belonged to the `accordion-button` not `accordion-header`.

```html
<div class="w-50 mt-5 mx-auto">
  <div class="accordion favorites-folder" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <div class="accordion-header">
        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Accordion Header
        </button>
        <div class="btn-group dropup position-absolute end-0 top-0 me-1 mt-2 px-2 zindex-2">
          <button type="button" class="header-actions" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical"></i>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
            <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button"> Rename</button></li>
            <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Delete</button></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a enim quis justo lacinia ullamcorper quis ac nunc. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer vitae nisi vitae eros iaculis interdum tempor a sapien. Nulla pulvinar, mi quis tincidunt tristique, eros elit venenatis arcu, in dapibus dolor turpis eget nisi.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.favorites-folder {
    background-image: none;

    .accordion-item {

        .accordion-header {
            position: relative;
            .accordion-button {
                z-index: 1;
                background-color: #fff;
                padding: .5rem 1rem;

                &:not(.collapsed) {
                    background-color: #fff;

                    &::after {
                        background-image: none;
                    }
                }

                &:after {
                    background-image: none;
                }
            }

            .header-actions {
                background: transparent;
                border: none;
                z-index: 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```